# Delete last 3 elements in list c++

Tags: c++, stl

I have this c++ code which works fine in deleting the last 3 elements of a list, but i was wondering if it's the correct way to do such a thing since i am worried of deleting elements with iterators issues.
The code basically takes a list of 6 elements "Groups", divides it into 2 smaller lists "Group1" and "Group2", and then compares a different List "GroupToCompare" to "Group2" and if they're equal it removes the last 3 elements of "Groups".

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::list <string> Groups = {};
    Groups = { "Spike", "Jet", "Faye", "Edward", "Vincent", "Elektra" };
    std::list<string> Group1 = {};
    std::list<string> Group2 = {};
    std::list<string> GroupToCompare = {};
    GroupToCompare = { "Edward", "Vincent", "Elektra" };

    size_t half1 = Groups.size() / 2;
    std::list<std::string>::iterator ig = Groups.begin();
    advance(ig, half1);
    Group1.insert(Group1.end(), Groups.begin(), ig);
    Group2.insert(Group2.end(), ig, Groups.end());

    std::list<std::string>::iterator removeIt = Groups.begin();
    advance(removeIt, half1);

    cout << "List Elements 1: " << endl;
    std::list<string>::iterator itrofList = Group1.begin();
    string firstvar;
    for (itrofList = Group1.begin(); itrofList != Group1.end(); ++itrofList) {
        firstvar = *itrofList;
        cout << "Item: " << firstvar << endl;
    }

    cout << "List Elements 2: " << endl;
    std::list<string>::iterator itrofList1 = Group2.begin();
    string firstvar1;
    for (itrofList1 = Group2.begin(); itrofList1 != Group2.end(); ++itrofList1) {
        firstvar1 = *itrofList1;

        cout << "Item: " << firstvar1 << endl;
    }

    if (Group2 == GroupToCompare) {
        removeIt = Groups.erase(removeIt);
        removeIt = Groups.erase(removeIt);
        removeIt = Groups.erase(removeIt);
    }

    cout << "List Elements of Groups after removing the last 3 elements: " << endl;
    std::list<string>::iterator itrofList2 = Groups.begin();
    string firstvar2;
    for (itrofList2 = Groups.begin(); itrofList2 != Groups.end(); ++itrofList2) {
        firstvar2 = *itrofList2;

        cout << "Item: " << firstvar2 << endl;
    }


}
```

is there a more correct way in case i wanna delete more elements in the end of the list and avoid deleting issues with iterators?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, read [mcve].

Comment: Why don't you use [`pop_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/pop_back) (or `pop_front`)

Comment: @hellow seems like a good idea. (Y)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though calling [`std::list::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) multiple times with the returned position works, calling the correct overload would help with readability and possibly performance:

```
iterator erase( iterator first, iterator last );
```

Example:

```
std::list<int> l{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
l.erase(std::prev(l.end(), 3), l.end());
// l is {1, 2}
```

Beware: as-is, this code exhibit undefined behavior if `l` is not at least 3 in size.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more **correct** way to do it?

Not sure what that means, but im assuming you would be interested in learning std::list has a public member function *pop_back* which deletes the last element in a list. Using this seems ideal for your case.

Note: As stated in this [refference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/pop_back/)

> If the container is not empty, the function never throws exceptions
>   (no-throw guarantee). Otherwise, it causes undefined behavior.

So make sure the list is never empty when you call this function.

Answer (score 0):

I would just...

```
std::list <string> Groups;

...

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    Groups.pop_back();
```